# How to move files inside Azure Devops and retain history?

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml

I moved some project to Azure Devops and I would like to move a file from folder1 to folder2 without losing the history of the file.

I tried by using this pipeline but the history was not copied with the file:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'folder1'
    Contents: 'file.txt'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/folder2'

- script: |
   git config --global user.email "myemail@email.com"
   git config --global user.name "me"
   git remote update
   git fetch
   git checkout master
   git add $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/folder2/file.txt
   git status
   git commit -m "copy files"
   git push origin master
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not lose history" _exactly_? Just in case, to explain a little bit about git: movements of files is something that git _infers_ because of the way information about the files in a commit is kept, Movement of files is not something that is _kept_ anyhow by git. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: the title of the question seems to indicate you want to do an action on your repo (as in: a generic git action, which could be applied on any git repository), but then your question mentions a pipeline (as in: a job run on a separate machine in response to an action on the remote repository) running explicitly in Azure Devops. Can you please clarify your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the *Moving Files* in [Git Basics - Recording Changes to the Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository), you can use the `git mv` command to move files and keep the history.

Sample yaml:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |
   git config --global user.email "myemail@email.com"
   git config --global user.name "me"
   git remote update
   git fetch
   git checkout main
   git mv test.txt newfolder/test.txt
   git status
   git commit -m "Moved test.txt to new directory"
   git push origin main
```

Result: we can find the history of the file.

[image]

Comment: It worked, I just had to change the "main" to "master" and make sure the folder "newfolder" existed. thanks!